# Difference between Flash and Microsoft Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, video-streaming, adobe, flash

can anyone explain the different between Flash and Silverlight to me?

I understand Flash in a program which can export SWF or FLV formats for users to play on the web using Flash Player. How does Silverlight compare to this? Is it a player or a development tool? Also does it export video file types such as those Netflix uses?

Comment: This is way off-topic and too broad for stack overflow.  This belongs on a forum somewhere.  Silverlight would be more comparable to FlashPlayer than FlashPro.   Silverlight is not a development tool. Visual Studio is what people generally use to create content for the Silverlight player.  For video on the web, just use the html5 `<video>` tag with a flash player fallback.

Answer (score 1):

The differences are many, but the main difference is they are competing products from competing companies (Microsoft Silverlight/Adobe Flash). Both are on the way out of favor, but still continue to be used for functions that have not been 100% replaced with open standards yet. Such as video codec support and DRM.

Answer (score 1):

Too many. I have worked on both and Flash is my favorite. Just go Wiki for the difference. I think if you have any specific question related to that which says any particular feature needed to be compared, that will be good.